# Ggarrange and annotate_figure producing two outputs in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
ptn<-egg::ggarrange(pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4,pt5,pt6, ncol = 2, nrow = 3,widths = c(0.5, 0.5))

annotate_figure(ptn, top = text_grob("Title",color = "red", face = "bold", size = 14))
```

This produces two plots in R markdown. One with title and one without title. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try with `ggpubr::ggarrange`.